# Auth.User.None when rendering a ManyToManyField

Tags: django, python-3.x, for-loop, django-templates

I am trying to render a ManyToManyField from a model that render a list of hotels with staff that belong to each hotel.

I am trying to display in the template the users that are inside the current hotel being shown but I get an error

```
auth.User.None
```

**my template**

```
{% for Hotel in object_list %}
         {{ Hotel.collaborateurs }}
              {% endfor %}
```

**My models.py**

```
class Hotel(models.Model):
collaborateurs = models.ManyToManyField(User, verbose_name="Liste des collaborateurs autorisés")
              (....)
```

Thanks

**Edit ;**

I am able to rend users but I have an unesthetic code being render : .

I would like to render only the username.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `.all` as manytomany relations are always lazy loaded in django.

```
Hotel.collaborateurs.all
```

Moreover variable names should be lowercase in Python.

`collaborateurs =` need an indent on the left side.

Hope that helps.

Comment: That works but it render something like "<User: gg>]>" in my template which is not what I excepted in clear

Comment: Override `__str__()` method to change that.

Answer (score 0):

**models.py**

```
class Song(models.Model):
user = models.ManyToManyField(User)
song_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
song_duration = models.IntegerField()

def written_by(self):
    return ",".join([str(p) for p in self.user.all()])
```

**html file**

```
    {% for data in data %}

        {{data.written_by}}   # It returns username
        {{data.song_name}}
        {{data.song_duration}}

    {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
{{ Hotel.collaborateurs.all.count }}
```

and that will provide the total number.