# Problem with Displaying the Output of models.ManyToManyField(User)

Tags: python, django, user-input

I am learning Django by building an application, called TravelBuddies. It will allow travelers to plan their trip and keep associated travel items (such as bookings, tickets, copy of passport, insurance information, etc), as well as create alerts for daily activities. The application will also able to update local information such as weather or daily news to the traveler. Travelers can also share the travel information with someone or have someone to collaborate with them to plan for the trip.

I am facing a problem. I have added two activities for Kuala Lumpur through Django admin. They are "Going to Botanical Garden" and "Going to Aquaria."

When I go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/triplist/, I see this page:
[image]

As you can see, in the Co-planner field, the name of the user is being displayed as `<QuerySet [<User: williams>]`>.But it is supposed to be displayed as `Co-planner: williams`.

Same problem occurs when I click on **Trip Name: Kuala Lumpur** and taken to http://127.0.0.1:8000/triplist/kuala-lumpur/:
[image]

Here are my codes in `models.py`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify

class Trip(models.Model):
    trip_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date = models.DateField()
    planner_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    add_coplanner = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, default='null')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.trip_name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.trip_name)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

class Activity(models.Model):
    trip = models.ForeignKey(Trip, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    activity_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    time = models.TimeField(auto_now= True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    item_type = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    item_number = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    add_cotraveller = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, default='null')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.activity_name

    def save(self):
        super(Activity, self).save()
        self.slug = '%i-%s' % (
            self.id, slugify(self.trip.trip_name)
        )
        super(Activity, self).save()
```

Here are my codes in `views.py`:

```
from django.views import generic
from .models import Trip, Activity


class TripListView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'trips/triplist.html'
    context_object_name = 'all_trips'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Trip.objects.all()


class ActivityView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Trip
    template_name = 'trips/activity.html'
```

Here are my codes in `urls.py`:

```
from . import views
from django.urls import path

app_name = 'trips'

urlpatterns = [
    path('triplist/', views.TripListView.as_view(), name='triplist'),
    path('triplist/<slug:slug>/', views.ActivityView.as_view(), name='activity'),
]
```

Here are my codes in `apps.py`:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class TripsConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'trips'
```

Here are my codes in `triplist.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% extends 'trips/base.html' %}
{% load static %}
<html lang="en">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "css/style.css" %}">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    {% block title%}Trip list{% endblock %}
    <title>Trip list</title>
</head>


<body>
    {% block content %}
    <!--Page content-->
    <h1>This is Trip List Page</h1>


    <ol>
        {% for trip in all_trips %}
        <ol>
            <li><a href="{% url 'trips:activity' trip.slug %}">Trip name: {{ trip.trip_name }}</a></li>
            Date: {{ trip.date }}<br>
            Planner: {{ trip.planner_name }}<br>
            Co-planner: {{ trip.add_coplanner.all }}<br>
        </ol>
        {% endfor %}


    </ol>

    <img src="{% static "images/botanical-garden.jpg" %}" alt="Botanical Garden" />
    <!-- New line -->
    {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>

</html>
```

Here are my codes in `activity.html`:

```
{% extends 'trips/base.html' %}
{% block title%}
Detail
{% endblock %}


{% block content %}

<h3>Activities for {{trip.trip_name}} </h3>

{% for trip_item in trip.activity_set.all %}
<!--<p>Activity name: {{ trip_item.activity_name }}</p>-->
<ol>
    <li>Activity name: {{ trip_item.activity_name }}</li>
    Date: {{ trip_item.date }}<br>
    Time: {{ trip_item.time }}<br>
    Location: {{ trip_item.location }}<br>
    Item Type: {{ trip_item.item_type }}<br>
    Item No: {{ trip_item.item_number }}<br>
    Co-traveller: {{ trip_item.add_cotraveller.all }}
</ol>
{% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

Is there anything wrong with triplist.html and activity.html?

**Update 1:** By the way, I got the idea of this code `add_coplanner = models.ManyToManyField(User)` from this link: [Auth.User.None when rendering a ManyToManyField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54953783/auth-user-none-when-rendering-a-manytomanyfield).

The person who asked the question also faced the same issue like me. He was getting something like `<User: gg>]>`. He was advised to override **str**() method. But I don't understand how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate here since it is the queryset

triplist.html

```
  Coplanners: 
    {% for user in trip.add_coplanner.all %}
        {{user.name}} 
        #{{user.username}} do this if your User model don't have name field
     #If you want to separate the users with comma
       {% if not forloop.last %} , {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}<br>
```

Comment: I have added your codes. However, the name of the user is not showing up. It is showing up as `Coplanners:`, not as `Coplanners: William`.

Comment: Are you indicating about this line: `add_coplanner = models.ManyToManyField(User)`

Comment: I have used this code: `{{i.add_coplanner.username}}` Same problem. The name of the user is not showing up.

Comment: By the way, I got the idea of this code `add_coplanner = models.ManyToManyField(User)` from this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54953783/auth-user-none-when-rendering-a-manytomanyfield. The person who asked the question also faced the same issue like me. He was getting something like `<User: gg>]>`. He was advised to override __str__() method. But I don't understand how to do it.

Comment: Yes. It works. Here are the working codes: `<ol>
        {% for trip in all_trips %}
        <ol>
            <li><a href="{% url 'trips:activity' trip.slug %}">Trip name: {{ trip.trip_name }}</a></li>
            Date: {{ trip.date }}<br>
            Planner: {{ trip.planner_name }}<br>
            Coplanners:
                {% for user in trip.add_coplanner.all %}
                    {{user.username}}
                {% endfor %}<br>
        </ol>`

Comment: I am facing a new problem. Would you please take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59189229/django-problem-with-separating-the-two-user-names

Answer (score 1):

Hi in 'Activity' model add this

```
    def get_cotravellers(self):
          return " , ".join([x.username for x in self.add_cotraveller.all()])
```

in templeate call it as `{{ trip_item.get_cotravellers }}`

Comment: I have added your codes. It gives me this error: `AttributeError at /triplist/kuala-lumpur/
'User' object has no attribute 'name'`

Comment: sorry updated. make it as username or first_name or what ever.

Comment: I am facing a new problem. Would you please take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59189229/django-problem-with-separating-the-two-user-names

Comment: Above code solves your problem.but my example is for `Activity Model`

Answer (score 0):

**models.py**

```
class Song(models.Model):
user = models.ManyToManyField(User)
song_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
song_duration = models.IntegerField()

def written_by(self):
    return ",".join([str(p) for p in self.user.all()])
```

**html file**

```
    {% for data in data %}

        {{data.written_by}}   # It returns username
        {{data.song_name}}
        {{data.song_duration}}

    {% endfor %}
```

*Relate Like This It Will Work*